# ElasticSearch 7.17, как правильно искать по списку UUID?

Tags: elasticsearch

Создаю индекс (id это uuid):

```
...
 "mappings": {
    "_field_names": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "id": {"type": "keyword"},
        ...
    }
  }
...
```

Закидываю данные. Далее зная список uuid, мне нужно получить данные из эластика.

Запрос:

```
{
  "_source": ["id", "city_code", "country_code", "name_en", "name_ru", "name_es", "name_fr", "name_it", "name_de", "name_uk"],
  "query": {
    "terms": {"id" : ["31bbcedb-3ca4-4de6-91b1-62683ec79a4f", "cfd24807-c758-444c-b38c-0a06dbccfe02"]}
  }
}
```

В результате пустота. При чем, если сделать такой запрос:

```
{
  "_source": ["id", "city_code", "country_code", "name_en", "name_ru", "name_es", "name_fr", "name_it", "name_de", "name_uk"],
  "query": {
    "terms": {"id" : ["31bbcedb", "cfd24807"]}
  }
}
```

Данные прилетят. Типа ему не нравится символ "-".

Как такое лечится ?

Comment: Уверены, что у вас `"id": {"type": "keyword"}` ? Проверьте в `GET index_name/_mappings`, это поведение типично для `text` полей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, данные в ElasticSearch по дефолту хранятся токенами. Каждый раз, когда вы сохраняете документ c текстовым полем, ElasticSearch дробит значение на отдельные слова и формирует сложную структуру, которая модифицируется в наиболее эффективную, подстраиваясь под api-запросы. Если эти GUID-значения являются идентификаторами документов в вашем индексе (насколько я вижу, это так), то должен работать [query ids](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) запрос:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "ids" : {
      "values" : ["31bbcedb-3ca4-4de6-91b1-62683ec79a4f", "cfd24807-c758-444c-b38c-0a06dbccfe02"]
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. сам не проверял, т.к. нет сейчас возможности. Дайте знать, если не сработает, подыщем другой запрос

---

Для поиска полного совпадения по полю нужно использовать `terms query` с `.keyword` постфиксом. Работает и на текстовых полях, однако с точки зрения эффективности такой способ крайне плох для стандартных текстовых полей:

```
{
   "query": {
     "terms": {
       "id.keyword": ["your_id_1", "your_id_2"]
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/HMWH1SZ.png

как я понимаю нет, это не основной id

Comment: @Nepster да, ваш индекс - это обычное поле в документе. Попробую подыскать другой запрос для вас позже. А пока вопрос: вы не можете перестроить структуру хранения данных, чтобы идентификаторами документа были GUID-значения?

Comment: `да, ваш индекс...` - имел ввиду "ваш id"

Comment: @Nepster обновил ответ

Comment: Да это оно, я как раз случайно разыскал. не успел ответить. большое спасибо